# Bootable Windows USB drive with custom application

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, encryption, livecd

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I boot and run windows XP from a USB flash memory stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/30530/can-i-boot-and-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-memory-stick)
>   [How to run windows 7 from a USB thumb drive](https://superuser.com/questions/36489/how-to-run-windows-7-from-a-usb-thumb-drive)

I want to run an application dealing with sensitive information (bank account data) on a not entirely trustworthy computer.

My idea now was to create a Live Windows on a USB drive with just this one application installed. The Windows installation itself can (and maybe should) be read-only, but some data needs to be saved on either this USB drive or a second one. Access to the internet is also required, but it would be nice if I could restrict it to a certain address.

I would prefer a Windows 7 version, just because of the better driver support.

What would also be nice is encryption of the USB drive (e.g. using Truecrypt).

I've never used a Windows Live CD, so is it possible to do all that? What is the easiest way to create a Live Windows on a USB drive and to preinstall my application?

Comment: Possible for XP: possible duplicate of [Can I boot and run windows XP from a USB flash memory stick?](http://superuser.com/questions/30530/can-i-boot-and-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-memory-stick)

Comment: Win7 seems hard/impossible:  [how-to-run-windows-7-from-a-usb-thumb-drive](http://superuser.com/questions/36489/how-to-run-windows-7-from-a-usb-thumb-drive)